# Unable to reference self in closure when defining property

Tags: swift, swift2

I saw this example online somewhere:

```
let newButton:UIButton = {
   let button = UIButton()

    return button
}()
```

when I add:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("someAction"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

I receive the error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

Just looking for clarification on why I cannot reference self here and how I can potentially make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference `self` because the constant gets set before `self` is initialised.

You could solve the issue by declaring it as `lazy var` instead of `let`. By declaring it `lazy var` you are telling that you want the `var` to be initialised the first time it is used:

```
lazy var newButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("someAction"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return button
}()
```

As a side note, with Swift 2.2 you should define selectors as `#selector(YourClass.someAction)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're writing this inside of a class scope (not inside a method, etc).  Based on a little experimentation, it seems that `self` will be a reference to the class type, not an instance.  This is probably because in `Swift` you cannot reference `self` during the initialization process prior to all fields being initialized and any necessary calls to an initializer on `super` happening.

If you need the property to be a constant, you would have to do this in an initializer, obeying the order requirements for initialization:

```
let newButton: UIButton

init() {
    newButton = UIButton()

    super.init()

    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("someAction"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```